# Chrome "[file] is not commonly downloaded ..." when downloading from local server

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, download

Hello StackExchange community,
I am trying to redistribute a software tool over the servers in our client's network because most of them don't have an internet access.
So the current situation is: I put the file on the Server and create a link to it on a html based website. When downloaded with Google Chrome You get the infamous message

> [file] is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous.

which has been solved before, but since it is a third party tool we cant sign it ourselfes.
The server is running apache 2.2.16 if that is part of the issue.

A quite whierd thing is, that we have another test server, on which there is no problem at all. The apache error page holds the following information about it:
`Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny8 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0 Server at ... Port 80`.
How can I avoid this message?

Thank you in advance.